# Using ADFS in VSTO add in

Tags: c#, security, dependencies, vsto, adfs

I am wondering if it is possible to make a client for ADFS in an add in developed in VSTO?

My problem until now is that I cannot use or find

`Microsoft.Interop.Security.AzRoles`

Does anybody know if it is possible to get into a VSTO add in? And if so, any information about how would be really helpful.

Thank you.